# Merging into sheets into 1 sheet - Incorrect Range width

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to merge several sheets into 1 spreadsheeet and want to paste all data below each other.

My current code looks like that:

```
function updateMaster() {

  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var repArray  = new Array();

  // build array of all sheets
  for (i in allSheets) {                              
    repArray.push(allSheets[i].getName());
  }

  // store all sheets in array
  var sheetArray = [];   
  // loop through all rep sheets                             
  for (var j in allSheets) {       
    // get each sheet                    
    var tempSheet  = ss.getSheetByName(repArray[j]);  
    // get sheet data
    var dataRange  = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
    // remove the first header row
    dataRange.splice(parseInt(0), 1);                 
    // append sheet data to array
    var sheetArray = sheetArray.concat(dataRange);    
  }

  // Time to update the master sheet
  var mSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");        
  // clear the whole sheet
  mSheet.clear({contentsOnly:true});                 
  // write to the Master sheet via the array 
  mSheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetArray.length, 4).setValues(sheetArray); //I GET THE ERROR BECAUSE OF THIS LINE
  // force spreadsheet updates
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();                   
  // pause (1,000 milliseconds = 1 second)          
  Utilities.sleep("200");                             

  // delete empty rows at bottom
  var last = mSheet.getLastRow();                     
  var max  = mSheet.getMaxRows();
  if (last !== max) {mSheet.deleteRows(last+1,max-last);}
}
```

However, I get an error, because other sheets have not the same column length.

The error message:

```
Incorrect range width, was 5 but should be 4
```

Here I get the error:

```
mSheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetArray.length, 4).setValues(sheetArray);
```

I basically, just want to post the data below. Any recommendation how I could make the column length variable?

Here is a link to my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TuHaqs20PvNwOJ46bQOAwN3Nt5vyRl7Win1Lul4m-e8/edit?usp=sharing

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

The `sheetArray` array has inner row elements of different lengths.  Some inner arrays have 4 elements, some have 5 elements.  You can't set values from an array with different inner element lengths.  If you change the column width to 5, the error states that it should be 4, if you change it to 4, it says that it should be 5.  You need to either add an extra empty element to the range with 4 columns, or write each sheet to the master individually.

Get one of the inner arrays, and find the length of an inner array.  That is your column length.

On this line:

```
var dataRange  = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

You are using the `getDataRange()` method.  That causes the range to be different dimensions for each sheet that has a different number of columns.  If you set the column width to the biggest number of columns in the sheet with the most columns, then all your inner elements would be the same length.  Your code would write a lot of empty cells.  But don't know if there is any downside to that .

```
var columsToWriteTo = sheetArray[0].length
mSheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetArray.length, columsToWriteTo).setValues(sheetArray);
```

The above code gets the first inner array of the two dimensional `sheetArray`, and gets the length of the inner array.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I immediately tried it out, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer pointed the issue but did not provide a solution.

What you should simply do is to make the final array homogeneous before setting its value with `setValues()`.

Below is a code demo that does it by adding empty items in rows that are too short. I added comments in code to explain

```
function ArrayNormalize() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data1 = sh.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues(); // get data from sheet1
  var data2 = sh.getSheets()[1].getDataRange().getValues();// same from sheet2 that has a different width
  var combine = data1.concat(data2);
  Logger.log("combine = "+JSON.stringify(combine));
  //get Max array width
  var maxWidth=0
  for(var n=0;n<combine.length;n++){
    Logger.log(n+'  - '+combine[n]+"  length = "+combine[n].length);
    if(combine[n].length>=maxWidth){maxWidth=combine[n].length};
  }
  Logger.log("maxWidth = "+maxWidth);
  //normalize
  for(var n=0;n<combine.length;n++){
      while(combine[n].length<maxWidth){
        combine[n].push('');// while row is shorter add empty "cells" (=array elements)
      }
  }
  sh.insertSheet().getRange(1,1,combine.length,combine[0].length).setValues(combine);// insert the result in new sheet to check the result but you can insert it anywhere else of course
}
```